# google image recognition recaptcha in php

Tags: php, recaptcha

working on an application in which I have to integrate google image recognition recaptcha like this

[image]

I have searched a lot and checked this one also [google recaptcha plugin](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php#client-side-how-to-make-the-captcha-image-show-up) but didn't got much success if any one has integrated it , please guide me how can I achieve this in php

Comment: You have not given enough information. What did not work, did you get any errors. Paste your code here so somebody can have a look at it.

Comment: @EvisBregu I have used the code from above given link but it is showing so much error and the message is showing the library is deprecated now

Answer (score 0):

First you need to follow the steps outlined here and save the api key that is generated: [reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list)
After that you need to download recaptchalib.php file. [recaptchalib.php](https://code.google.com/archive/p/recaptcha/downloads)
And here you have a simple example how it works.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
<?php

require_once('recaptchalib.php');

// Get a key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
$publickey = "";
$privatekey = "";

# the response from reCAPTCHA
$resp = null;
# the error code from reCAPTCHA, if any
$error = null;

# was there a reCAPTCHA response?
if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]) {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        if ($resp->is_valid) {
                echo "You got it!";
        } else {
                # set the error code so that we can display it
                $error = $resp->error;
        }
}
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
?>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this answer be better than the last.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12770048)

Comment: I hope this answer be better than the last.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i want the captcha that is shown above not this which you mentioned here

Comment: The first time shows no picture, but if you click more times then the captcha displays the image selector

Answer (score 0):

For this it is divided in two parts

1)Front End - which has your form element & google captcha image

2)BackEnd Part - to check validation of captcha image

Here is code :-

1)Front End

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<form action="" method="post">
 <!-- captha div -->
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data- sitekey="your-site-key-from-google-captcha"></div>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

***When you submit form it will automatically update the field "g-recaptcha-response"***

Now for the second part to check whether the captcha code is true or false.

2)Back End

```
if(isset($_POST)){

       $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                "secret=your-site-key-from-google-captcha&response=".($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]!==""?$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]:"")."&remoteip=".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
            // receive server response ...
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $server_output = json_decode(curl_exec ($ch),1);

            curl_close ($ch);

          if(($server_output["success"])==true){
               echo "captcha is valid";
            }else{
                echo "captcha is not valid ";
            }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i want the captcha that is shown above not this which you mentioned here

Comment: bro please try with this one .When you do first captcha it will display images when you visit same website with same ip then it won't ask for image to select.

Comment: you are telling me that it is the same captcha that i was requested above ?